# How to store datas in jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I want to collect every id of `div` that has been clicked then assign that value to a `var`.

Here is my code:

```
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    var el = el + ', ' + $(this).attr('id');
    alert(el);
});
```

I tried this one, but every time I click `el` it's reset, how can I prevent it from resetting?

Comment: last line is showing my anger. I tried more than 10 times to upload this one but failed with no reasonable reason. so don't take it serious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the initial declaration of `el` outside of your click event:

```
var el = '';
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    el += ', ' + $(this).attr('id');
    alert(el);
});
```

This causes the variable to live in another scope.

And you should use arrays instead:

```
var el = [];
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    el.push( $(this).attr('id') );
    alert(el.join(", "));
});
```

Comment: how do you call += stuff? because i knew answer to my question would look something like that but i couldn't find any proper name to search it on google

Comment: You call this to concatenate or append. @adeneo: You're totally right, of course. I just wanted to show him how his approach would look like first. I added an array version of his code.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it in an array. Makes it easier to use later. (My opinion)

```
el=[];
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    el.push($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A further iteration of the answers given before is to test if an item has previously been added before

```
var ids=[];

$('div.kim2bb').on( 'click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    // if id has not been added before
    if( ids.indexOf( id ) == -1 ) {
        ids.push( id );
    }
    console.log( ids.join( "," ) );
});
```